# Rename specific columns in data frames in a list that meets condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df1) and a list (l) of data frames (df2, df3):

```
df1 <- tibble(a = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555))

df2 <- tibble(a = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55), 
              b = c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555),
              c = c(11111, 2222, 333, 4444, 55555),
              d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

df3 <- tibble(a = c(11, 22, 333, 44, 55), 
              b = c(11211, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555),
              c = c(11111, 2222, 333, 4444, 55555),
              d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

l <- list(df2, df3)
```

I need to find the values in the list that match the values in df1. Only those data frames in the list should be kept, that have exactly one column with matched values The data frames that have less or more than 1 column with matched values should be dropped. The columns in the data frame that stay should be renamed, for example "thiscolumnhastruevalues". In the example above df2$c should be renamed. df3 should be deleted from the list, as it has more than one column with TRUE values.

I tried several approaches with "match" "%in%" "apply" "rename" but i cant get to my destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one base R option -

```
lapply(l, function(df) {
  #count number of df1$a values in each column
  count <- colSums(sapply(df, `%in%`, df1$a))
  #IF exactly one column has that value
  if(sum(count > 0) == 1) {
    #change the column
    names(df)[count > 0] <- 'value'
    df
  } else NULL
})

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      a     b value     d
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    11  1111 11111     1
#2    22  2222  2222     2
#3    33  3333   333     3
#4    44  4444  4444     4
#5    55  5555 55555     5

#[[2]]
#NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(l, ~ tryCatch({.x %>% 
    rename_with(~ "value", select(., where(~ any(. %in% df1$a))) %>% 
        names)}, error = function(err) NULL) )
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      a     b value     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    11  1111 11111     1
2    22  2222  2222     2
3    33  3333   333     3
4    44  4444  4444     4
5    55  5555 55555     5

[[2]]
NULL
```